# Troubleshooting Dockerfile build: ERROR – this error may indicate docker daemon is not running

Tags: build, dockerfile, operating-system

today I was following a tutorial of how to make an OS with kernel.
When I try to build the dockerfile appears this error:

> ERROR: error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker
> daemon is not running: Get
> "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open
> //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find thot find the file
> specified.

I am using this command: docker build buildenv -t myos-buildenv

My code is this:

```
FROM randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nasm
RUN apt-get install -y xorriso
RUN apt-get install -y grub-pc-bin
RUN apt-get install -y grub-common

VOLUME /root/env
WORKDIR /root/env
```

I'm trying to build the code from dockerfile. But when I open Docker it closes automatically. I am in Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

Comment: The error says that the docker daemon isn't running. You need to provide information about your system because it's either A. You didn't start the docker process and are using the command line tool without docker running or B. Your system settings are not right for the docker command line to connect to the docker process to run the command. Your dockerfile scripts are not at the point of being executed yet, so the information you provided is not helpful at the moment. I hope this makes sense.